# For ループの処理中に IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

forの多重ループを用いて複数の .xlsx ファイルを順に読み込ませ、
BV、T1、T2、T3の４パターンを目的変数として選択し、
それ以外のcolumnsを消して
機械学習モデルのプログラムを作成していました。

```
for a in range(0,4,1):
 l1=['AP','ES','ET','FP']
 b=l1.pop(a)
 c=".xlsx"
 for d in range(0,4,1):
  df = pd.read_excel(b+c)
  l2=['BV','T1','T2','T3']
  del l2[d] 
  df.drop(l2, axis=1,inplace=True)
  df.isnull().sum()
  df.dropna(inplace = True)
  df.isnull().sum()
  l3=['BV','T1','T2','T3']
  X = df.drop(l3[d], axis=1)
  Y = df[l3[d]]
  X=X.astype('str')
  Y=Y.astype('str')
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=0)
  model = RandomForestClassifier()
  model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
  with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
   print(b,file=f)
   print(l2[d],file=f)
   print("RFtrain score:",model.score(X_train,y_train),file=f)
   print("RFtest score:",model.score(X_test,y_test),file=f)
   print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred),file=f)
```

しかし、以下のようにエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 24, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

rangeがミスであると思われますが、構文のミスがわからなかったので教えていただけると幸いです。
※一周目の内側のループは出力できていました。

Comment: `del l2[d]` としていますので、`d` が `3` の場合に `l2[d]` において当該のエラーが発生することになります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメント欄でのアドバイス通り、以下の記述を `l3[d]` に直したところ直りました。

```
print(l2[d],file=f)
```